# MySQL stored procedure - How to get last insert id

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have created one stored procedure which inserts a record into table and gets auto incremented ID of that record. Here I am getting an syntax error while setting `LAST_INSERT_ID()` into a variable.

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near ');
> SET _orderId = SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(); END' at line 5

Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in Advance.

My code is like below:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE placeOrder(IN _cartId INT, IN _createdBy INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE _orderId INT;
     
    -- insert into order
    INSERT INTO `TBL_ORDER`(`DealerId`, `OrderNo`, `CreatedBy`)
    VALUES ((SELECT DealerId FROM TBL_SHOPPING_CART WHERE Id = _cartId), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), _createdBy)); 
    SET _orderId = SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();

END//
 
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE placeOrder(IN _cartId INT,IN _createdBy INT)
BEGIN
SET @orderId = '';
-- insert into order
INSERT INTO `TBL_ORDER`(`DealerId`, `OrderNo`, `CreatedBy`) VALUES ((SELECT DealerId FROM TBL_SHOPPING_CART WHERE Id =  _cartId),UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),_createdBy)); 

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @orderId;


END//

delimiter ;
```

OR

```
delimiter //
    CREATE PROCEDURE placeOrder(IN _cartId INT,IN _createdBy INT)
    BEGIN

    -- insert into order
    INSERT INTO `TBL_ORDER`(`DealerId`, `OrderNo`, `CreatedBy`) VALUES ((SELECT DealerId FROM TBL_SHOPPING_CART WHERE Id =  _cartId),UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),_createdBy); 

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS '_orderId ';


END//

delimiter ;
```

Comment: I have updated the answer. Hope it is what you are looking for.

Comment: Will you use that variable in Procedure again OR you will use it in your Model? Otherwise you can also use it as SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS "_orderId "

Comment: can you explain what exactly you want to do with the result?

Comment: After doing some calculation, I want to update that particular record in same transaction...

Comment: I have added the second queries which might help you. You can get the fetch the result in the model and it will return last inserted ID into the "_orderId " column then you can reuse it in same transaction.

Comment: where you added the query ?

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '); 
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS '_orderId ';

END' at line 7

Comment: There was a extra closing bracket in your query.

Comment: Ohhhh......Thank you Thank you sooooo much Rohit... You have no idea how much this has helped me. Keep it up bro... god bless you....

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that your application is not having a global connection or shared connection. As `last_insert_it()` will return the **last generated AI value** it can be from any table. Especially if your host application is using async TASKs

Consider following scenario

1. Your application saves gps location every second => generating new AI value
2. You're trying above SP to insert a value => Generating new AI value
3. Between your insert and read last_insert_id, your application logs gps location again and created new AI value.
4. Now guess what happens? you get the last inserted id from the gps table not from your SP.

usually insert's are fast, but assume your SP had to wait for a table lock and got delayed. In such case, you will receive wrong ID.

Safest way can be to escapsulate your SP work within a transaction and get the max value of your AI column (assuming it's an unsigned AI column).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```sql
...
-- SET _orderId = SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
SET _orderId = LAST_INSERT_ID();
SELECT _orderId;
...
```

or

```sql
...
-- SET _orderId = SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
SET _orderId = (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());
SELECT _orderId;
...
```

Comment: @rahulshalgar: See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0198c81163a45ed632b8792e4be63624).