# Insert command not inserting or throwing error, does return @@IDENTITY

Tags: python, mysql, stored-procedures

I am running a Stored Procedure to insert a new row into a table and return the Auto-Generated ID.
However, it doesn't insert the row but does respond correctly with the id when calling it from Python. (Eg it returns 9 but when looking in the DB where is no new message)

Running the command using SQL Workbench does work as expected

The SP being called is addNewMessage and expects 3 parameters(sUID, roomid, message)

**SQL command (when running manually)**

```
CALL addNewMessage('bfc1cc8c-4462-11ea-887c-000d3a7f4c7f', '658946602274258955', 'My Message')
```

**SQL SP**

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `messages`(`server_uid`, `title`, `message`, `author`, `room_id`) VALUES (sUID,title,'','',room);
SELECT @@IDENTITY as newId;
END
```

**Python Scripts**

```
new_message = mysql_command('discord_addNewMessage', ['bfc1cc8c-4462-11ea-887c-000d3a7f4c7f', '658946602274258955', 'My Message'])
print(new_message);
```

```py
def mysql_command(command, args, addDataWrapper=False, decode=False):
    global sql_cursor
    try:
        if isinstance(args, list):
            sql_cursor.callproc(command, [arg for arg in args])            
        else:
            sql_cursor.callproc(command, [args])
        for result in sql_cursor.stored_results():
            return_data = result.fetchall()
            if decode:
                data = return_data[0][0].decode('utf-8')
            else:
                data = return_data[0][0]
            if addDataWrapper:
                data = '{"data":[' + data + ']}'
            return data
    except BaseException as ex:
        print("SQL Error :", ex)
```

Comment: Use next for  return last inserted id from stored procedure: SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS 'newId ';  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50304821/mysql-stored-procedure-how-to-get-last-insert-id

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev I've done that and still returns the ID, but no row is inserted when calling from the Python script

Answer (score 1):

After some more digging, I needed to commit using `mydb.commit()` after the `sql_cursor.callproc`